# Can't run python bash script through crontab (python installed via anaconda)

Tags: python, bash, cron, anaconda

I have a script written in python. Console launch successful. For this script, I made a bash script, this is how it is designed:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/anaconda3/bin/activate
python /home/user/RosAtom-V/Work/StopCoronaVirus.py
conda deactivate
```

[image]

It also runs successfully through the console, but it prints the following error:

```
Could not find conda environment:
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info —envs`.
```

Then I open the crontab in order to automate it, but the script does not start and I get the following message in the log file. How can I format the bash script correctly so that I do not receive these errors and everything works?

[image]

Error in log file:

```
/home/user/RosAtom-V/Work/start_StopCoronaVirus.sh: line 3: python: command not found
Could not find conda environment:
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info —envs`.
```

Before that, all the scripts were run, just the other day I began to receive this output with an error

Comment: Did you try to write full python path in your bash ?

Comment: @Ptit Xav, no, we can say that I inherited these files, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Path to the `python` and `conda` binaries is defined in your *ENV* variables. Crontab does not load environment variables from `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, etc. since it runs non-interactively.

To run crontab jobs with ENV see some [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/load-env-variables-in-cron-job).